# knockout foreach data bind on grouped data

Tags: .net, json, jquery-mobile, knockout.js, igrouping

I'm trying to figure out how to iterate through a .Net grouping using the knockout foreach data-bind.  The issue I have is that I don't know how to iterate over a .Net collection of IGroupings once it's been serialized to JSON...

On the server side I have a .Net object that looks like this:

```
public class BookingResult
{
    public IEnumerable<IGrouping<DateTime, BookingLeg>> Grouped { get; set; }
} 

public class BookingLeg
{
    public string DepartureDate { get; set; }
    public string ArrivalDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
}
```

And I'm creating the `Grouped` property by grouping a collection of `BookingLeg` entities by their `StartDate`.  I then return the `BookingResult` entity using JSON.  The JSON that is generated for the `Grouped` property looks like this (I've collapsed and expanded the nodes to give you a better overview of what was generated):

[image]

What I'd like to do on my client is create a template and bind to the knockout foreach binding outputting the key as a list header and then for every value in that key, output some details from the value.  It would look something like this:

```
01/01/2012
  - Transfer
  - Flight
  - Transfer
03/01/2012
  - Transfer
  - Cruise

...
```

I've attempted to do this like so:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-bind="foreach: Grouped">
    <li data-role="list-divider"><span data-bind="text: Key"></span></li>
    <li data-bind="text: Name, click: $parent.getBookingLegDetail"></li>
</ul>
```

I know the above is wrong, for one - Key doesn't exist in Grouped.

**Does anyone know how I can create a template to correctly output the Key and Values of my grouping in a list?**  BTW I'm also using jquery mobile here (hence the data-role stuff).

Thanks!

James

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaScriptSerializer doesn't handle the Key property in IGrouping objects. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1449142/360053) question for a similar problem and possible solutions.

Comment: I decided to go the way of a new type with a key and value.  I can't figure out how to iterate over the value though!  Going to post another question...  Thanks though!  I'm almost there!