# Serialize object as its concrete class, not IEnumerable

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

Given the following class:

```
public sealed class GorpCollection : IEnumerable<Gorp> {
   private readonly IReadOnlyCollection<Gorp> _gorps;
   public GorpCollection(string name, IEnumerable<Gorp> gorps) {
      _gorps = gorps.ToList().AsReadOnly();
      GorpType1 = _gorps.Where(gorp => gorp.GorpType == 1).ToList().AsReadOnly();
      GorpType2 = _gorps.Where(gorp => gorp.GorpType == 2).ToList().AsReadOnly();
      Name = name;
   }

   public string Name { get; }
   public IReadOnlyCollection GorpType1 { get; }
   public IReadOnlyCOllection GorpType2 { get; }

   public IEnumerator<Gorp> GetEnumerator => _gorps.GetEnumerator();
   IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable) _gorps).GetEnumerator();
}
```

I would like to serialize it as its concrete class to a JSON object, and not as an `IEnumerable` which comes out as an array. I am content for the properties `Name`, `GorpType1`, and `GorpType2` to be serialized.

What is the easiest way to do this with the least messing about with custom converters, binders, and settings? I would have thought a simple attribute was available such as `[SerializeAs(typeof(GorpCollection))]`. But a fair amount of searching later, and I still don't know a simple way to get this done.

Comment: Have you tried `[JsonObject]` (more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15058402/23354, which was the first hit for "json.net ignore ieumerable" in google)?

Comment: Hi @MarcGravell, I swear to you I did a fair amount of searching and did not find that. But now I see that my question is a duplicate of that one. Thank you very much! I think the attribute is not well-named to hint what it does. Even an IEnumerable is an object. :)

Comment: @ErikE naming is hard :) For protobuf-net, I went with `[ProtoContract(IgnoreListHandling = true)]` - which  kinda explains a bit more

Comment: @Rafal What exactly are you unclear on? I don't want to deserialize, I want to serialize. As I said, I am content for the properties `Name`, `GorpType`, and `GorpType2` to be serialized. If you still need an example, here's the result I'm looking for: `{"Name":"Silly","GorpType1":["A gorp"],"GorpType2":["Another gorp"]}`. I do not want `["A gorp","Another gorp"]`.

Comment: @ErikE a yes got it now :)